# 8K stack size in linux

Tags: linux

I want to run a process which has 7 threads internally with 8K stack size for each thread in a linux system(fedora 18)

I gave the below command in the terminal before I run my process

```
$ulmit -s 8   //Want to run my process and its threads each with 8K stack size

$./a.out  // I started my process
```

With this command system hanged up and there is no response.But when I give the command

```
$ulimit -s 16 //MY process successfully started.
```

When I tried with 8K, before setting 8K I have changed the `PTHREAD_STACK_MIN`(in /usr/include/bits/local_lim.h) value to 8192 and by default it was 16384.

Can we run the process with 8K stack size? Is there any lower limit ? or Is it that any thread in my process consuming more than 8K stack size ?

Comment: The ulimit stack *only applies* to the main thread's stack, not to any of the threads that are created. Why are you trying to run threads with a size smaller than `PTHREAD_STACK_MIN`? It's the supposed minimum size needed to *enter* your thread routine.

Answer (score 0):

PTHREAD_STACK_MIN should not be set too low. At startup, the process will call libc functions to start threads and run the program. It is not a good idea to reduce below the default size in a system. The stack-min is not just for the variables in your function. It is also used for the system calls that happen at process/thread startup.